# Monge's shuffle questions on permutations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

I am naive in number theory and having problems in finding the following exercise questions. Please some one help me with these questions. I want to thank you all in advance. :-)

The first part of questions are following:

> Let consider a heap of m different cards. The trick is the following: Someone
>       draws a card from the heap. He-She puts it in some place into the heap.
>       The cards are shuffled (several times) according to a given permutation.
>       The objective of this game is to guess this card.
>
> Let consider the following particular permutation: Take the first card
>       of the pile, then, the second one is placed above, the third is placed below
>       and so on alternatively until the initial heap becomes empty. This trick has
>       been introduced and analyzed by the famous french mathematician Gaspar
>       Monge (1746-1818). The question here is to prove the following properties.

1. Show that for m = 10 the card in the fourth position remains fix. Is it
   still true for odd m?
2. Show that for any m the initial order always appears once again 1 . In
   particular, how many steps are required for m = 24?
3. Generalize the previous results: for m = 6k + 4 prove that the card in
   position 2k + 2 always remains unchanged.
4. For some values of m, show that there exist two cards that are always
   exchanged. Apply this to m = 22.

The Second part of questions are following:

> The following trick sounds magical. The question is to determine how it
>       works 2 . The process involves 3 persons, the description is as follows:
>       Divide the 52 cards in 3 packets with roughly the same size. Give a packet
>       to each person and ask them to look at the card above the heap. Now, each
>       person guesses a number between 10 and 15 (let S i be this number for the
>       i-th person).

1. Shuffle in each packet the S i top cards (shuffle here means to put
   the top card at the bottom, and so on).
2. Distribute the packets among the persons (i receives the packet from
   i − 1 modulo 3).
3. Shuffle again the packets with the guess number.
4. Redistribute the packets (i receives the packet from i − 1 modulo 3)
   and shuttle it again.
5. After the traditional "abracadabra" incantation, the cards are back
   at the top of each packet.

Comment: The help center has pages on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and just as importantly [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), ~ ~ ~ ~  This sequence of questions is clearly intended to lead you from simple to more complex cases, to help your understanding. You would do well to attempt them yourself, and only post a question to this site when you are ready to describe your own efforts and *detailed* problems.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on this as soon as I will find difficulty I shall post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some concepts to use as you work through these questions. I also recommend reading the first sections of [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) on wikipedia.

Imagine that, before the permutation starts, you number the cards $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ etc. Then what does the deck look like after one permutation? For the seven-card deck, there, it would build up as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\{&1\}\\
\{2,\,&1\}\\
\{2,\,&1,3\}\\
\{4,2,\,&1,3\}\\
\{4,2,\,&1,3,5\}\\
\{6,4,2,\,&1,3,5\}\\
\{6,4,2,\,&1,3,5,7\}\\
\end{align}
$$

Are any cards left in their original position? if we compare:
$$
\{6,4,2,1,3,5,7\}\\
\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\\
$$

...We can see that just one card remains unchanged here.

And what happens if we repeatedly apply the permutation?
$$
\color{blue}{\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}}\\
\{6,4,2,1,3,5,7\}\\
\{5,1,4,6,2,3,7\}\\
\{3,6,1,5,4,2,7\}\\
\{2,5,6,3,1,4,7\}\\
\{4,3,5,2,6,1,7\}\\
\color{blue}{\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}}\\
$$

Now do the same for the 10-card deck.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on this as soon as I will find difficulty I shall post it here.